# Can't install applications because of LUKS encryption and partitioning

Tags: partition, kali-linux, luks

I installed Kali into my machine along with another operating system and one thing I did was manual partitioning to encrypt the whole Kali partition using this [guide](https://www.informaticar.net/how-to-manually-partition-and-encrypt-kali-linux/). Now whenever I try to update I get an unmet dependencies error and when I try to fix it or install a third party application, in this case being Mullvad VPN, I get the following type of error.

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/g++-10_10.2.1-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/cc1plus' to '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/cc1plus.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

The following is the full output of when I try to run **sudo apt --fix-broken install**

```
└─# sudo apt --fix-broken install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cpp-10 g++-10 gcc-10
Suggested packages:
  gcc-10-locales g++-10-multilib gcc-10-doc gcc-10-multilib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cpp-10 g++-10 gcc-10
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 827 not upgraded.
21 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/135 MB of archives.
After this operation, 454 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 312949 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../g++-10_10.2.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking g++-10 (10.2.1-1) over (10.2.0-16) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/g++-10_10.2.1-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/cc1plus' to '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/cc1plus.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../gcc-10_10.2.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-10 (10.2.1-1) over (10.2.0-16) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-10_10.2.1-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/lto1' to '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/lto1.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../cpp-10_10.2.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cpp-10 (10.2.1-1) over (10.2.0-16) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cpp-10_10.2.1-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/cc1' to '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/cc1.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/g++-10_10.2.1-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-10_10.2.1-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cpp-10_10.2.1-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now I'm not sure how to continue. I was thinking if I should resize the partitions but that doesn't make sense because I'm certain there is enough space. It's just not recognized.

Another thing that I have noticed is that looking at the folder properties in /, some directories such as /root/, /opt/, and /usr/ are full and don't have anymore space. The /root/ being full makes sense to me because I partitioned for the /root/ directory but the /opt/ and /usr/ directories are strange to me because I didn't partition for those directories.

Here's the output of when I run **df**

```
└─# df
Filesystem                  1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                          8129460       0   8129460   0% /dev
tmpfs                         1633860    1428   1632432   1% /run
/dev/mapper/CryptoKali-Root   9545920 9478772         0 100% /
tmpfs                         8169292       0   8169292   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                            4096       0      4096   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/CryptoKali-var    9545920 1913256   7128040  22% /var
/dev/mapper/CryptoKali-tmp    9545920   36944   9004352   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/CryptoKali-home  68066648 1042392  63523612   2% /home
/dev/sda5                      945144   94196    785720  11% /boot
tmpfs                         1633856      56   1633800   1% /run/user/1000
```

I know there are other ways to install and use Kali such as a persistant live USB or Virtual Machine, but I want to do dual booting and make it work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

> I was thinking if I should resize the partitions but that doesn't make sense because I'm certain there is enough space. It's just not recognized.

Your `df` output shows that `/` *is* full, which is where all your `apt` errors are coming from. You should reduce `/home` and increase `/`.

Comment: Or I guess add a `/usr` partition and move the existing contents of `/usr` on the root partition there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've realized that my dumb mistake was thinking / == /root/ in the partitioning process during installation. I've resized it and everything is working now.